# Cannot create AdRequest instance by pyjnius

Tags: android, admob, kivy, pyjnius

I'm trying to install AdMob on Kivy. I import AdRequest successfully but cannot create its instance.

```
AdRequest = autoclass("com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest")
print "AdRequest: ", AdRequest
print dir(AdRequest)
```

In the logcat, I can see the properties and methods of AdRequest by dir() :

```
AdRequest <class 'jnius.reflect.com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest'>
['DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR', 'ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR', 'ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST',        
'ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR', 'ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL', 'GENDER_FEMALE', 'GENDER_MALE',   
'GENDER_UNKNOWN', 'MAX_CONTENT_URL_LENGTH', '__class__', '__cls_storage', 
'__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', 
'__init__', '__javaclass__', '__javaconstructor__', '__module__', '__new__',   
'__pyx_vtable__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', 
'__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'equals', 'getBirthday', 
'getClass', 'getContentUrl', 'getCustomEventExtrasBundle', 'getGender', 'getKeywords', 
'getLocation', 'getNetworkExtras', 'getNetworkExtrasBundle', 'hashCode', 
'isTestDevice', 'notify', 'notifyAll', 'toString', 'wait']

AttributeError: type object 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest' has no attribute    
'Builder'
Python for android ended.
```

I cannot find the Builder method
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.html
It's a class method to build AdRequest

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `AdRequest.Builder` is not a method, it is a nested class. So you need to pull in the right class using [nested class syntax](http://pyjnius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#jnius.autoclass):

```
AdBuilder = autoclass('com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder')
```